# Lag Function on Group SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is how my table looks.

```
    PID JNo EV Phase    Name
    100 1   1   NULL    Test1
    101 2   2   NULL    Test2
    102 3   3   NULL    Test3
    103 4   4   1       Test4.1
    103 4   4   1       Test4.2
    103 4   4   1       Test4.3
    104 5   5   3       Test5.1
    104 5   5   3       Test5.2
    104 5   5   3       Test5.3
    105 6   6   3       Test6.1
    105 6   6   3       Test6.2
    105 6   6   3       Test6.3
    107 7   7   NULL    Test7.1
    107 7   7   NULL    Test7.2
    107 7   7   NULL    Test7.3
```

I have to create a column which says whether my phase has been changed or baselined.

For example:

- For `PID=100` first phase is null so it should be Baselined.
- For `PID=101` phase is null. Previous value (100) it was null so it should be baselined for 101. Similarly for 102 it should be null.
- For `PID=103` phase = 1. Previous value was (102) it was null. So it should be PhaseChange.
- For `PID=104` phase = 3. Previous value was (103) it was 1 so it should be PhaseChange.
- For `PID=105` phase = 3. Previous value was (104) it was 3. So it should be Baselined.

Sample data:

```
PID JNo Ev  Phase   Name    PCH
100 1   1   NULL    Test1   Baselined
101 2   2   NULL    Test2   Baselined
102 3   3   NULL    Test3   Baselined
103 4   4   1       Test4.1 PhaseChange
103 4   4   1       Test4.2 PhaseChange
103 4   4   1       Test4.3 PhaseChange
104 5   5   3       Test5.1 PhaseChange
104 5   5   3       Test5.2 PhaseChange
104 5   5   3       Test5.3 PhaseChange
105 6   6   3       Test6.1 Baselined
105 6   6   3       Test6.2 Baselined
105 6   6   3       Test6.3 Baselined
107 7   7   NULL    Test7.1 PhaseChange
107 7   7   NULL    Test7.2 PhaseChange
107 7   7   NULL    Test7.3 PhaseChange
```

Code sample:

```
create Table #SampleTable
(ProjectID int,
JustNo int,
ERev int,
Phase int,
Name varchar(100) )

insert into #SampleTable values(100,1,1,Null,'Test1') 
insert into #SampleTable values(101,2,2,Null,'Test2')   
insert into #SampleTable values(102,3,3,Null,'Test3')   
insert into #SampleTable values(103,4,4,1,'Test4.1')   
insert into #SampleTable values(103,4,4,1,'Test4.2')   
insert into #SampleTable values(103,4,4,1,'Test4.3')   

insert into #SampleTable values(104,5,5,3,'Test5.1')   
insert into #SampleTable values(104,5,5,3,'Test5.2')   
insert into #SampleTable values(104,5,5,3,'Test5.3')   
insert into #SampleTable values(105,6,6,3,'Test6.1')   
insert into #SampleTable values(105,6,6,3,'Test6.2')   
insert into #SampleTable values(105,6,6,3,'Test6.3')   
insert into #SampleTable values(107,7,7,null,'Test7.1')   
insert into #SampleTable values(107,7,7,null,'Test7.2')   
insert into #SampleTable values(107,7,7,null,'Test7.3')   

select * from #SampleTable
```

I tried using the `Lag` function no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a subquery to calculate previous state and assign an unique row_number. Then use `DENSE_RANK()` to asign the same id to each group.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b59489/27)**

```
WITH phases as (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
         ProjectID,
         Phase,
         DENSE_RANK() over (ORDER BY ProjectID) as rn      
  FROM SampleTable
), table_rank as (
  SELECT *,
         DENSE_RANK() over (ORDER BY ProjectID) as rn           
  FROM SampleTable
)
SELECT t.*, p.*,
       CASE WHEN p.Phase IS NULL AND t.Phase IS NULL THEN 'Baselined'
            WHEN p.Phase = t.Phase THEN 'Baselined'
            ELSE 'PhaseChange'
       END PCH
FROM table_rank t
LEFT JOIN  phases p
       ON t.rn = p.rn + 1
```

**OUTPUT**

I put extra columns so you can debug the result.

```
/ --            table_rank                       -- / --          phase_rn      --/
| ProjectID | JustNo | ERev |  Phase |    Name | rn | ProjectID |  Phase |     rn |         PCH |
|-----------|--------|------|--------|---------|----|-----------|--------|--------|-------------|
|       100 |      1 |    1 | (null) |   Test1 |  1 |    (null) | (null) | (null) |   Baselined |
|       101 |      2 |    2 | (null) |   Test2 |  2 |       100 | (null) |      1 |   Baselined |
|       102 |      3 |    3 | (null) |   Test3 |  3 |       101 | (null) |      2 |   Baselined |
|       103 |      4 |    4 |      1 | Test4.1 |  4 |       102 | (null) |      3 | PhaseChange |
|       103 |      4 |    4 |      1 | Test4.2 |  4 |       102 | (null) |      3 | PhaseChange |
|       103 |      4 |    4 |      1 | Test4.3 |  4 |       102 | (null) |      3 | PhaseChange |
|       104 |      5 |    5 |      3 | Test5.1 |  5 |       103 |      1 |      4 | PhaseChange |
|       104 |      5 |    5 |      3 | Test5.2 |  5 |       103 |      1 |      4 | PhaseChange |
|       104 |      5 |    5 |      3 | Test5.3 |  5 |       103 |      1 |      4 | PhaseChange |
|       105 |      6 |    6 |      3 | Test6.1 |  6 |       104 |      3 |      5 |   Baselined |
|       105 |      6 |    6 |      3 | Test6.2 |  6 |       104 |      3 |      5 |   Baselined |
|       105 |      6 |    6 |      3 | Test6.3 |  6 |       104 |      3 |      5 |   Baselined |
|       107 |      7 |    7 | (null) | Test7.1 |  7 |       105 |      3 |      6 | PhaseChange |
|       107 |      7 |    7 | (null) | Test7.2 |  7 |       105 |      3 |      6 | PhaseChange |
|       107 |      7 |    7 | (null) | Test7.3 |  7 |       105 |      3 |      6 | PhaseChange |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here.  2 things to keep in mind.  The initial load will show as phasechanged since there was no previous to compare to.  Also, when phase is null it has to be replaced by a value to compare against the previous one (and vise versa) so I used an isnull and replaced nulls with -1.  Ideally they would not be null or make sure you replace null with a value that will not be used normally.

```
DECLARE @SampleTable TABLE
(ProjectID int,
JustNo int,
ERev int,
Phase int,
Name varchar(100) )

insert into @SampleTable values(100,1,1,Null,'Test1'),(101,2,2,Null,'Test2'),(102,3,3,Null,'Test3'),(103,4,4,1,'Test4.1'),(103,4,4,1,'Test4.2'),(103,4,4,1,'Test4.3'),(104,5,5,3,'Test5.1'),(104,5,5,3,'Test5.2'),(104,5,5,3,'Test5.3'),(105,6,6,3,'Test6.1'),(105,6,6,3,'Test6.2'),(105,6,6,3,'Test6.3'),(107,7,7,null,'Test7.1'),(107,7,7,null,'Test7.2'),(107,7,7,null,'Test7.3')


select
    PROJECTID
    ,JUSTNO
    ,EREV
    ,PHASE
    ,NAME
    ,CASE LAG(ISNULL(PHASE,'-1')) OVER (ORDER BY PROJECTID, PHASE)
        WHEN ISNULL(PHASE,'-1') THEN 'BASELINED'
        ELSE 'PHASECHANGED'
        END AS PHC
from @SampleTable
```